# A Characterization of the Strong Markov Property

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have a question concerning the strong Markov property:

For a strong Markov process $(X_u)_{u\ge 0}$, a real time $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and an optional stopping time $T$ with $t< T$

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}((X_u)_{u\ge T}\in B \mid (X_u)_{u\le t}\in A , X_T=x )\\
= \mathcal{P}((X_u)_{u\ge T}\in B\mid X_T=x)\quad, a.s.
\end{align*}

How can I show that

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}((X_u)_{u\le t}\in A, (X_u)_{u\ge T}\in B \mid X_T=x)\\
= \mathcal{P}((X_u)_{u\le t}\in A\mid X_T=x) * \mathcal{P}((X_u)_{u\ge T}\in B\mid X_T=x)) \quad a.s.?
\end{align*}

Is this even true?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Can you define the notation?  What is $(X_u)_{u \ge T}$?  What is the state space?  What kind of sets are $A,B$?

Comment: I'm sorry. The state space is a polish space $S$, $A$ is a Borel subset of $S^{[0,t]}$ and $B$ is a Borel subset of the space of forward paths on the state space $S$. $(X_u)_{u\le t}$ is the Markov process between time 0 and t; $(X_u)_{u\ge T}$ is the Markov process after the stopping time $T$ was realised.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with $\sigma$-algebras, then you could start by demonstrating that 
$$
P(F\cap G|{\mathcal C}) =P(F|{\mathcal C})\cdot P(G|{\mathcal C}),\quad\forall F\in{\mathcal A},G\in{\mathcal B}
$$
is equivalent to
$$
P(G|{\mathcal C}\vee{\mathcal A}) =P(G|{\mathcal C}),\quad\forall G\in{\mathcal B}.
$$
Here ${\mathcal A}, {\mathcal B},{\mathcal C}$ are three $\sigma$-algebras of events in your probability space, and ${\mathcal C}\vee{\mathcal A}$ is the least $\sigma$-algebra containing both ${\mathcal C}$ and ${\mathcal A}$. (The equalities in both displays above should be understood to hold almost surely.)

Having shown this, consider the special case in which ${\mathcal A}=\sigma\{X_{\min(t,T)}: t\ge 0\}$, ${\mathcal B}=\sigma\{X_{T+s}: s\ge 0\}$, and ${\mathcal C} =\sigma\{X_T\}$. In this way the strong Markov propery is seen to be equivalent to the time-symmetric conditional independence property in your second display.